# Web Master Tools API Search Analytics Ver 3

Tags: php, google-api-webmasters

I am using Google Web master tools API v3 for Search Analytics. I am using Service Account to retrieve the analytics. I received following message.

(403) User does not have sufficient permission for site 'http://www.1800medexpress.com/'. See also: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2451999.'

I added Service Account Email address also to the Web Master tools as owner. But still received same error.

I used PHP API Library.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried but this should work.

In [Webmaster tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/) for the website in question.   upper right hand corner there is a cogwheel click on it go to `Users and Property Owners` click add a new user button add your service account email address.

Then try and run your code.

Service accounts need to be granted access to the data just like you would any other user by default they don't have access to your data.

**Update:**

By checking the documentation we can see that it is in fact possible to use a Service account with [webmaster tools api](https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/v3/how-tos/authorizing#service-accounts) it just needs to be set up properly.  It may be an issue with your code or how you have set it up.  Clod should probably be simlar to this.  [Service account with Google Calendar](http://www.daimto.com/google-calendar-api-with-php-service-account/)

> A service account is used in an application that calls APIs on behalf
>   of an application that does not access user information. This type of
>   application needs to prove its own identity, but it does not need a
>   user to authorize requests. The Google Accounts documentation contains
>   more details about service accounts.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I should need Google Web master tools searchanalytics query. here is the URl [link](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?hl=en_US#p/webmasters/v3/)

Comment: I found cog wheel. When am clickign on that one it showing Search Console Preferences only. Wil you please provide detail information on that one.

Comment: @DalmTo I added Service Account Email address to the Web site as an owner already. I added to 2 sites. But still receiving the same error to me.

Comment: I am not sure if webmaster tools supports service account authentication.  I will try digging into the documentation

Comment: @DalmTo thanks for the response. I have any solution to resolve the issue. Please inform if any body already worked on this one.

Comment: Is any body had solution about this